# Scala / Neo4J - Removing/ deleting a relationship path between nodes and returning true or false as result

Tags: scala, neo4j, relationship

I'm attempting to remove a relationship between two specific nodes by their ID. I've tried the following:

```
def deleteRelationship(nodeAID: String, nodeBID: String)(implicit neoFormat: NeoFormat[Node]) : Future[Boolean] = {
    val txn = storeAPI.NeoTransaction()
    val deleteQuery =
      s"""
         | MATCH relationship = (a: $NODE_A {id: "$NodeAID"})-[r]-(b: $NODE_B {id: "$NodeBID"})
         | DELETE r
       """.stripMargin
    txn.querySingle(deleteQuery).flatMap {
      result =>
        txn.commit().map (_ => true)
    }.recoverWith {
      case e: Exception =>
        logger.error(s"Error during deleteRelationship", e)
        txn.rollback().map{_ => false}
    }
 }
```

I am trying to delete the relationship between the two specific nodes. When I try to run it, the method returns false. I suspect that it has something to do with the query rather than the scala method, but I have included it anyway.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: where are NODE_B and NODE_A?

Comment: Can you check the spellings of parameters? It's case sensative

Comment: @Raj They are substitutes for node types. Parameter spelling is fine also.

Comment: The correct query would be `MATCH (: $NODE_A { id: "$NodeAID" })-[r]-(: $NODE_B { id: "$NodeBID" }) DELETE r` - You were trying to delete a path, not a relationship. BTW, this will delete all relationships between a & b, maybe you also want to match an specific relationship. Also, are those ids the internal ones used by Neo4j? If so, stop using them. Finally, as you said this is not related to Scala at all, I would recommend you to use the Neo4j web console to try your queries before adding them to your app.

Comment: if you receive `false` that means  you  have an exception. Can you give the detail of the exception ?

Comment: The query definitely works. But now I don't understand why the method is returning false. Could it be because `txn.querySingle(deleteQuery)` is expecting a result when a delete wouldn't actually return a result? or would a delete return a result?

Comment: SOLUTION: If I add `RETURN r` at the end of my query, it does take a result and then the method returns true. There is probably a better way of doing this so that if you're deleting then don't expect a result, but in my case it will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

`txn.querySingle(deleteQuery)` does expect a result. In the original method, a result wasn't being returned as designed. However, because of this, it was skipping the block with the `txn.commit().map(_ => true)` and therefore never returning true.

Adding `RETURN r` to the end of my query provides `txn.querySingle(deleteQuery)` with a result and therefore reaches the `txn.commit().map(_ => true)`.

I'm sure there is a better way to not rely on a result for a `DELETE` query, but this solves my issue for now.

Please feel free to add any better suggestions. I'll select the best answer if suggestions are provided.